# Resize UIView not working

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a uiview subclass that I am calling from a view controller.  It shows up and everything, but I am unable to resize it.  When i put a breakpoint on the initwithframe method of the view, it shows up unchanged, but the view controller is definitely changing it...

Here is my view controller code:

```
- (void)resizeWithTag:(int)tag wasTouched:(BOOL)touched

    {
        GameBox *tbox = (GameBox *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];
        CGRect frame = tbox.frame;
        frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
        tbox.frame = frame;
        [tbox setNeedsDisplay];
        NSLog(@"%f", tbox.frame.size.width);
    }
```

and here is the init method and draw method of uiview subclass

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]];
        name = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    }
    return self;
}



// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    int border = 3;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sunflower.jpeg"];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
    CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height), border);
    [self attachImage:image inRect:rect inBorder:border];
    [name setFrame:CGRectMake(0 + border/2, rect.size.height-10-border/2, rect.size.width-(border), 10)];
    [name setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:9.0]];
    [name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0]];

    name.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self addSubview:name];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a breakpoint in `initWithFrame:` is not the right place to be looking. This will be called only once when you create the view.

Later on you are grabbing the view and changing it's frame property by calling `tbox.frame = someFrame` which is equivalent to calling `setFrame:`.

This line

```
NSLog(@"%f", tbox.frame.size.width);
```

should show that you did change the width.

Comment: Yes it does.  However the width does not change on the screen